# Unanswered Bounty

Tags: discussion, bounty

I have this question, which I put my first bounty on:  [VS 2015 Razor Autocomplete/Intellisense dropdown hides immediately after dropdown](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36212901/vs-2015-razor-autocomplete-intellisense-dropdown-hides-immediately-after-dropdow)

There's two answers, neither of which are correct.  The highest voted answer is highest voted because a) it's a month old, and b) it's *one context* in which the bug can be found.  However, in my question I show an easily reproducible example of how to replicate the bug that clearly shows the highest accepted answer is not fully correct.

Is there really no way to prevent that incorrect answer from being auto-accepted?  I don't really care about the bounty points (they're not mine anymore), but I'm not keen on this being an accepted answer, because it's not (people are going to google into the question later thinking *ah yes finally, an answer!* but... no dice).

Anyway, I'm posting in hopes that something has changed since the rants I've ready about this on meta from some years back.  I really don't want either answer to show as an accepted answer.

If I'd known this would happen, I would have never started a bounty.

Comment: If the answer is incorrect... why is it not downvoted.

Comment: 1) No answers will be _accepted_ by the system, only have the bounty awarded. 2) Only the second answer, with 2 score, qualifies for that much, as the answer has to be posted _after_ the bounty was created and have 2 or more rep. If you haven't downvoted it, that's the only way you could even possibly keep it from getting the bounty right now.

Comment: @Kendra - thanks, I hadn't realized that was the case... the old discussion I had read must have been for a prior behavior.  As such, this is fine then.

Comment: @Kendra see here: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4508/please-do-not-auto-select-answers-on-bounty-questions/ Apparently it used to be a feature and I didn't see the "status-completed" tag until now, as in it's a change they made.  Apologies the trouble, et al;

Answer (score 0):

> Is there really no way to prevent that incorrect answer from being auto-accepted?

There is no way for you to prevent the bounty from being automatically awarded.

Comment: It's check when the grace period ends.

Comment: Per the question, I care not about the bounty award, but about the accepted answer.  Kendra clarified for me in the comment on the question.